# Buffer for TCP connection

Tags: networking, tcp, buffer

I wanted to know if in TCP connection establishment , separate buffers each of size 2^16 bytes are allocated for separate TCP connections to separate Servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, separate buffers are allocated for send and receive. The amount of memory reserved initially depends on the default-configuration and if application chooses a different size using set_sockopt(). The initial reserved memory also grows as number of outgoing/incoming packets increase.

On Linux, the default values can be read/modified using the foll sysctls.

## sudo sysctl -a | grep tcp | grep mem

net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 191133       254845  16777216

net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096        16384   777216

net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096        16384   16777216

You can use setsockopt() with SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF to modify it from application.

Comment: I had a doubt that whether the client while establishing TCP connections with different servers allocates different buffers for each Server of size 2^16 ?

Comment: Yes, it does. It is 2^16 by default on Linux but it is also configurable. These buffers are per TCP connection irrespective of if it is to same server or not. Also, keep in mind that the buffer allocated is not used only to store data. It is also used to store skbuff and few other things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. There are certainly two buffers, send and receive, but the size is platform dependent, and can be modified by the application.

Comment: I had a doubt that whether the client while establishing TCP connections with different servers allocates different buffers for each Server of size 2^16 ?